# Error trying to zero-copy deserialize using serde in Cloudflare workers

Tags: rust, backend, webassembly, serde, cloudflare-workers

I have a struct containing `&str` with the same lifetime annotation as the struct itself. When I try to call the `first::<T>(None)` method on a `worker::d1::D1PreparedStatement`, which is supposed to query my database and parse the values into type `T`, I get "implementation of 'Deserialize' is not general enough".

Here some of my code:

```
use worker::;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct User<'a> {
    #[serde(with = "uuid_as_string")]
    uuid: Uuid,
    name: &'a str,
    display_name: &'a str,
    profile_text: &'a str,
    profile_picture_url: &'a str,
    email_address: &'a str,
    password: &'a str,
    created: usize,
    deleted: usize,
    timezone: isize,
}

mod uuid_as_string {
    use serde::{self, Deserialize, Deserializer, Serializer};
    use uuid::Uuid;

    pub fn serialize<S>(uuid: &Uuid, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where
            S: Serializer,
    {
        serializer.serialize_str(&uuid.to_string())
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'a, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Uuid, D::Error>
        where
            D: Deserializer<'a>,
    {
        let s = String::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        Uuid::parse_str(&s).map_err(serde::de::Error::custom)
    }
}

#[event(fetch, respond_with_errors)]
pub async fn main(request: Request, env: Env, _ctx: Context) -> Result<Response> {
    Router::new()
        .getasync("/", |, ctx| async move {
            let d1 = ctx.env.d1("D1_DATABASE")?;
            let statement = d1.prepare("SELECT FROM users");
            match statement.first::<User>(None).await? {
                Some(user) => Response::from_json(&user),
                None => Response::error("Not found", 404),
            }
        })
        .run(request, env)
        .await
}
```

I tried completely removing the `Uuid` field and the module for handling it and it didn't change anything.

Comment: We need more information. Please post the _full_ text of the error message as `cargo check` prints it.

Comment: What's `worker`? Is it the [`worker` crate](https://docs.rs/worker)?

Comment: BTW `uuid` implements serde traits with the `serde` feature - no need to reinvent the wheel with your `uuid_as_string` module.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't do zero-copy deserialization in this case. The signature of [`workers::d1::D1PreparedStatement::first()`](https://github.com/cloudflare/workers-rs/blob/1d307145d9114d3241932ed2965fb1c65e6a67a9/worker/src/d1/mod.rs#L159-L161) is as follows:

```rust
pub async fn first<T>(&self, col_name: Option<&str>) -> Result<Option<T>>
where
    T: for<'a> Deserialize<'a>,
{
    // ...
}
```

That `where T: for<'a> Deserialize<'a>` means that the deserialization must be owned (note that this is exactly how `DeserializeOwned` is [implemented](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeOwned.html#impl-DeserializeOwned-for-T)), and therefore "can be deserialized without borrowing any data from the deserializer."

You must remove the borrowing from your struct to use it in this context, perhaps by replacing the `&'a str` fields with owned `String`s.